# Matching users who reviewed the same restaurants

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on an algorithm which calculates a similarity coefficient between restaurants. Before we're able to calculate said similarity, I need 3 users who rated both restaurants. Here is a table with a possible scenario as example:

```
       | Restaurant 1 | Restaurant 2
User 1 |      X       |      2
User 2 |      1       |      5
User 3 |      4       |      3
User 4 |      2       |      1
User 5 |      X       |      5
```

Here does `X` stand for no review, and the ratings are reviews from a user for the restaurant. You can see it's possible to calculate a similarity because User 2, 3 and 4 rated both restaurants.

Because I'm using an [adjusted cosine similarity](http://www10.org/cdrom/papers/519/node14.html) I need the average of the ratings from each user.

Right now I'm retrieving a list of all restaurants and a double for loop to check if it's possible to calculate a similarity between restaurants.

I'm using the following double for loop to check if it's possible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allRestaurants.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < allRestaurants.Count; j++)
        if (i < j)
            matrix.Add(new Similarity()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FirstRest = allRestaurants[i],
                SecondRest = allRestaurants[j],
                Sim = ComputeSimilarity(allRestaurants[i], allRestaurants[j], allReviews)
            });
```

Inside `ComputeSimilarity` I use the following LINQ statement to check the amount of 'matches':

```
public double ComputeSimilarity(Guid restaurant1, Guid restaurant2, IEnumerable<Tuple<List<Review>, double>> allReviews)
{ //The double in the list of allReviews is the average rating of the user.
var matches = (from R1 in allReviews.SelectMany(x => x.Item1).Where(x => x.RestaurantId == subject1)
               from R2 in allReviews.SelectMany(x => x.Item1).Where(x => x.RestaurantId == subject2)
               where R1.UserId == R2.UserId
               select Tuple.Create(R1, R2, allReviews.Where(x => x.Item1.FirstOrDefault().UserId == R1.UserId)
                   .Select(x => x.Item2)
                   .FirstOrDefault()))
                   .DistinctBy(x => x.Item1.UserId);

int amountOfMatches = matches.Count(); //Don't mind this, not looking for performance here at the moment.
if (amountOfMatches < 4)
    return 0;
```

Now you can see this approach is very performance heavy and it takes a *lot* of time when you increase the amount of restaurants for the double for loop.

I figured a better approach would be to retrieve all restaurants which already meet this requirement, but I'm stuck on how to do this. I think you can retrieve a list of 'matches' which would be a list of tuples which would look like this: `Tuple<Review, Review, double>`. Where these reviews would be from the same user and the double is the average rating of the reviews from the user.

I have been trying several attempts, but I keep getting stuck when I want to add the condition where only restaurants need to be retrieved with the 3 matches.

For reference, my review object looks like this:

```
public class Review
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int Rating { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid RestaurantId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

    //More irrelevant attributes here
}
```

And my restaurant object:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    //More irrelevant attributes here
}
```

I'm looking for something that performs better than my current approach, is there anyone who can point me in the right direction or suggest a better approach? Also, if you need more information, let me know! Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The first example shows two restaurants, but the list can be larger of course. The point is where I only want restaurants for which it's possible to calculate a similarity.

So take the following example:

```
       | Restaurant 1 | Restaurant 2 | Restaurant 3
User 1 |      X       |      2       |     X
User 2 |      1       |      5       |     X
User 3 |      4       |      3       |     3
User 4 |      2       |      1       |     2
User 5 |      X       |      5       |     X
User 6 |      X       |      X       |     2
```

The only possible match is between restaurant 1 and restaurant 2. Because there aren't enough matches (In this case a minimum of 3), it's not possible to calculate a similarity. So the way to optimize this, is to create a list of restaurants where it *is* possible to calculate a similarity.

To explain further, a `match` is where 2 users rated both restaurants. `Restaurant 3` has 3 reviews, but only 2 of them are matches, since `User 6` has only rated that restaurant.

So if we would give the 3 restaurants above as input, it should only create a list of restaurants for which it's possible to calculate a similarity (In this case only restaurant 1 and 2).

**Edit 2:** I'll add an example how my desired output should look:

A 'match' is where at least 3 users have rated the same 2 restaurants. So let's say we have restaurant X and Y, an output could look like this:

```
       | Restaurant X | Restaurant Y
User 1 |      5       |      3
User 2 |      2       |      5
User 3 |      1       |      2
```

Now if we added a third restaurant to the list which each user also has reviewed:

```
       | Restaurant X | Restaurant Y | Restaurant Z
User 1 |      5       |      3       |      2
User 2 |      2       |      5       |      3
User 3 |      1       |      2       |      1
```

Now you can see it's possible to generate a similarity between each restaurant here. A similarity between X and Y, X and Z, Y and Z.

This can be modeled in a separate class like so:

```
public class Match
{
    public Review rev1 { get; set; } //These two reviews have been left by the same users, on separate restaurants.
    public Review rev2 { get; set; } 
}
```

If we have 3 of these matches where each object has the same `RestaurantId` from rev1 and the same `RestaurantId` from rev2.

So a list of these matches could look like this:

- Match 1: `rev1.RestaurantId = 1` | `rev2.RestaurantId = 2` | `UserId = 11` This UserId is the same on rev1 and rev2
- Match 2: `rev1.RestaurantId = 1` | `rev2.RestaurantId = 2` | `UserId = 12` This UserId is the same on rev1 and rev2
- Match 3: `rev1.RestaurantId = 1` | `rev2.RestaurantId = 2` | `UserId = 13` This UserId is the same on rev1 and rev2

I know the ids are guids, but this is purely as example.

I hope this made sense..

Comment: Can you explain a little what is it that you are computing in `ComputeSimilarity` function's linq,
What is the actual use case? You give two restaurants and output a match number or you give one  and output all restaurants with corresponding match with the specified one?
Show us how it is finally used, the input and expected output.

Comment: @MathewJibin excuse my English, but I explained it more in my post. Let me know if this clears stuff up!

Comment: Is there no UserId in Review object ? How do you find reviews of users ?

Comment: You're right, I forgot! Edited my post

Comment: One more thing, I don't understand your "matching rules". Let's say you have X users and Y restaurants. 
Is there a match when  at least 3 users have rated all of the Y restaurants ?
Or is there a match when at least 3 users have rated at least the same 3 restaurants ?

Comment: A match is where 1 user has left 2 reviews on 2 separate restaurants. It's possible to calculate a similarity when 3 users have done so. Totaling in 3 reviews on each restaurant.

Comment: @RandomStranger, What about my answer ? If it's correct, please mark as Answer, otherwise tell me where I am wrong so I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @Floc haven't had the time to look at it during the holidays. Was going to implement it today or tomorrow. I'll let you know when it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've done what you try to achieve.

I've built a database with the Reviews table in your post and I've put the same datas as the table you show us in your **Edit**.

---

**Step 1**

So, I first group by RestaurantId with values as a list of all the reviews of users that have rates this restaurant.

It gives us this :

[image]

**Step 2**

Exclude restaurants that have less than 3 reviews of users that have reviews less than 2 restautants.

It gives us this :

[image]

**Step 3**

We have now the right list of restaurants but we need to exclude the users reviews that are not in the match. Then flat all this to only have restaurants and reviews.

It gives us this, **this is the final result** :

[image]

---

**Here is the code :**

```
var matches = this.Reviews.GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantId, r => this.Reviews.Where(rr => rr.UserId == r.UserId))
    .ToList()
    .Where(g => g.Where(gg => gg.Count() >= 2).Count() >= 3);

var matchingReviewsByRestaurant = matches.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Where(g => g.Count() >= 2).SelectMany(g => g));
```

I hope it's what you wanted !

---

### Edit : Final Answer

Final answer, so here is what you want, pairs of reviews by users.

```
// Step 1 : Get the right reviews
var matches = this.Reviews.GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantId, r => this.Reviews.Where(rr => rr.UserId == r.UserId)).ToList()
.Where(g => g.Where(gg => gg.Count() >= 2).Count() >= 3);

var matchingReviewsByRestaurant = matches.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Where(g => g.Count() >= 2).SelectMany(g => g));

// Step 2 : Create the matching couples
var reviewsByUsers = matchingReviewsByRestaurant.SelectMany(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToLookup(r => r.UserId);

var matchingReviewsCouples = new List<Match>();

foreach (var reviews in reviewsByUsers)
{
    var combinations = reviews.SelectMany(x => reviews, (x, y) => new Match(x, y))
                              .Where(m => m.Review1.Id.CompareTo(m.Review2.Id) > 0)
                              .ToList();
    matchingReviewsCouples.AddRange(combinations);
}

// Final Results are in matchingReviewsCouples
```

And with the datas of my exemple, here is the result :

[image]

Comment: This is getting close, but what I'm confused on how to use this. Currently I'm getting a list of reviews per user who reviewed the restaurant (Which id is the key in the dictionary). I'll add an example to my post how my desired output should look, would it be possible to achieve that?

Comment: @RandomStranger Ok, I see what you want. But, if we stay on the data I was using, are you aware that this would lead to duplicates in your list of matches ? Lets say a match is `{ Review1Id, Review2Id }`. In my exemple, for user 3 (it will be the same with user 4), we will have this list of matches `[ {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 6} ]`. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Are those matches on the same restaurant? Then yes. Each match has to be on 2 different restaurants by the same user.

Comment: @RandomStranger I've updated my answer to match your needs.

Comment: My reviews have guids as ids, so the `<` operator won't work, is there a way to still compare them? Edit: I really appreciate all the effort you've put in your answer, I just wanted to thank you for that

Comment: @RandomStranger I've updated my answer. This is the new comparison to work with Guid : `.Where(m => m.Review1.Id.CompareTo(m.Review2.Id) > 0)`

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! I really appreciate all the effort you have put into your answer, this should be the new standard for SO ^^

Comment: I was reading you post and it disapears. Have you solved your issue ? I think it can be deferred enumerations that can lead to this behavior. Adding some ToList() can help. Tell me if your issue is still there or not.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the comparison on guids wasn't the error. I'm currently grouping on anonymous types which somehow makes my list size fluctuate each time I run the method. I'm working out why this works.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to group per match? So I'd have a list of matches per 2 restaurants? Grouping by anonymous type like so: `.GroupBy(x => new { FirstGuid = x.rev1.SubjectId, SecondGuid = x.rev2.SubjectId })` makes my list fluctuate in size..

Comment: Please go to chat.stackoverflow.com so we can discuss about it more easily. Then, we will post the answer here.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest followings;  ,
1) If you do not have huge amount users and restaurants,re consider usage of Guid.Make the id values int.Query of int types faster.

2) Your input datas just int.You can violate data redundacy to make faster query.You can find my sugesstion for data moddling.

```html
<Similarity>
  <Users>
    <User id="25">
      <Restaurants>
        <Restaurant id="1" rating="1"/>
        <Restaurant id="2" rating="2"/>
      </Restaurants>
    </User>
    <User id="26">
      <Restaurants>
        <Restaurant id="1" rating="3"/>
        <Restaurant id="2" rating="5"/>
      </Restaurants>
    </User>
  </Users>
  <Restaurants>
    <Restaurant id="1">
      <Users>
        <User id="25" rating="1"/>
        <User id="26" rating="3"/>
      </Users>
    </Restaurant>
    <Restaurant id="2">
      <Users>
        <User id="25" rating="2"/>
        <User id="26" rating="5"/>
      </Users>
    </Restaurant>
  </Restaurants>
</Similarity>
```

EDIT
According to your structure,maybe below 2 methods could be helpful.

```
public List<Review> RestReviews(Guid rIdThatYouWantoMatch)
{
    var reviewsOfOneRestaurant= this.Reviews.Where(r=> r.RestaurantId == rIdThatYouWantoMatch).ToList();

    if( reviewsOfOneRestaurant.Count() < 3)
    {
        return null;
    }

    else 
    {
        foreach (var review in reviewsOfOneRestaurant)
        {
            var user= this.Users.Where(u=> u.Id == review.UserId).SingleOrDefault();

            if( this.Reviews.Where(r=> r.UserId == user.Id).Count() < 2)
               reviewsOfOneRestaurant.Remove(review);
        }
        return reviewsOfOneRestaurant;
    }
}

public List<Match> MatchReview(List<Review> one,List<Review> two)
{
    List<Match> list=new List<Match>();

     foreach (var review in one)
     {
        var review2= two.Where(r=>r.UserId == review.UserId).SingleOrDefault();
        if( review2 != null)
        {
            Match match = new Match();
            match.rev1=review;
            match.rev2=review2;
        }
     }
     return list;
}
```

For query performance,
1) You should add rateCount to User table
2) consider to Restaurant based review storage.For every Restaurant you should make a table.
You can find suggested data structure below

```html
<Similarity>
  <Users>
    <User id="1" rateCount="1"/>
    <User id="2" rateCount="2"/>
    <User id="3" rateCount="3"/>
    <User id="4" rateCount="3"/>
    <User id="5" rateCount="1"/>
    <User id="6" rateCount="1"/>
  </Users>
  <Restaurants>
    <Restaurant id="1" userCount="3">
        <User id="2" rating="1"/>
        <User id="3" rating="4"/>
        <User id="4" rating="2"/>
    </Restaurant>
    <Restaurant id="2" userCount="5">
        <User id="1" rating="2"/>
        <User id="2" rating="5"/>
        <User id="3" rating="3"/>
        <User id="4" rating="1"/>
        <User id="5" rating="5"/>
    </Restaurant>
    <Restaurant id="2" userCount="4">
        <User id="2" rating="5"/>
        <User id="3" rating="3"/>
        <User id="4" rating="2"/>
        <User id="6" rating="2"/>
    </Restaurant>
  </Restaurants>
</Similarity>
```

Comment: I do have a large amount of users and restaurants, which is why we chose for Guids. Also, my question wasn't about increasing performance on the user of ids, thank you for your time though.

Comment: I do not know Tupple and similarity subjects.I just want to learn what you want to calculate? You want to calculate a restaurant's AVERAGE RATING if the restaurant is rated by at least 3 USERS ? Do you have any other condition to calculate the average rating of restaurant?

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question, but floc has helped me enough. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this is not just for you.This is for me and other programmers who have similar problems.If you do not have time not explain.But if you have time,please let me know simply what you to calculate?

Comment: In order to use an adjusted cosine similarity, I need the average rating of all reviews for each user that's used. I was planning to make this a scheduled job which recalculates a field per user, only when they have left a review that day.